# magento newsletter is only sending 4 out of 30 recipients

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

For some reason, magento newsletter is only sending 4 out of 30 messages to my subscriptors and then the queue ends, is there an error log where i could check and report to you guys? here is a screenshot of how it ends

[image]

here is the report log
http://pastebin.com/YjfgUXRv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm strange.

It could be a Magento related problem but it can also be a problem coming from your mail server.

First, you should try to look your `magento/var/log/system.log` and `exception.log`, to check if nothing is written there (assuming logs are enabled)

You can also check your apache2 / Nginx / other 's log file concerning your admin, to check is there are no exceptions.

Finaly, you should have a look at your `/var/log/syslog` to check if your sendmail (or exim or whatever) is not returning an error message.

Then, post it here and someone will be able to help you.

Comment: ok, here are the logs
APACHE LOG
http://pastebin.com/MacrfzPL
System.log
http://pastebin.com/mJqwFeJV
exception.log
http://pastebin.com/ueKXjYq6

the last one, /var/log/syslog i dont have such folder or file on my setup...let me know if that helps

Comment: any hints? im stuck here...

Comment: well there are errors in your logs, as in many ppl's log whehn they use community modules, which are often "not fully tested or bugfree". When I asked you the end of the concerned logs, I should have asked you to try and launch the newsletter 1st, then copy/paste the logs, so we can find things. Here, I see errors but they may not be related

Comment: your module HideCartPrice looks a bit buggy, but I don't think that's the reason leading to your newsletter not being sent. On the other hand, your exception.log indicates that there is a block which is invalid and throwing an error. When the newsletter is sent, if the block is indeed included in the newsletter, that might explain why it's not working ... so maybe that's a way to dig

Comment: Hmmm there is an imageslider block that is probably faulty, and it seems that you're trying to display this block in a 2-column layout page, and it's failing. So the slider is probably not rendering properly. But that's not your main e-mail problem.
If you don't have syslog, try with /var/log/messages

Comment: not messages either, the only files on my log folder are system.log exception.log and aschroder_smtppro.log which is the way messages are leaving out, and its the first log i place in the main question, here is the pastebin again http://pastebin.com/3MCbhUNA

on the other errors, the image slider that you mention is on the main page at http://distributor.doralworld.com the way its installed is how instructions showed... but cant tell you whats right or wrong...

Comment: now that you mention a block, i have a community module installed (which i paid for) that let me append products from my catalog to include in the mail, is there any related to that module? its called Category Newsletter

Comment: I don't see any errors in your smtppro.log.
About the block you include in your newsletter, can you please try NOT to include it, and then try to send the newsletter. If it works, it would mean that your module is throwing an error, preventing the e-mails from being sent.
Your error log is talking about a block that is failing to render. If it's THIS block, then it may explain the bug. Tell me when you have results.

Comment: i cant deactivate the module without removing it via ftp... so i emailed the company mage-shop who sold me the module to find a solution, i will let you know as soon as i heard from them...

Comment: if you have access to your magento, you should be able to edit the file /app/etc/modules/the_module.xml
Inside, just change from true, to false. Then you'll be able to rollback to true whenever you want. This will requiere you to fully clean the cache.

Comment: That worked!! i deactivate the module, and the newsletter was sent to all the customers... now the big question is.. how do i fix this module to work properly? because its important for me to work, cause i need to add products to the newsletter...

Comment: 1st : Reinstall the module and see if it's working.
OFC, check you have the latest version of the module
You can ask the module's developper about this problem.
Problem is : There is a Slider block, inserted by this module to your newsletter, and this slide block is not working properly (I mean it has an error, or it's not declared correctly in the module maybe, or you may have inserted faulty or broken products to display in this slider, like products with broken images or missing fields)
in any case : Check things separately to point out the bad component.

Comment: they decided to not reply to my problems, so i guess i will have to figure it out on my own...a paypal claim is on its way as well